# Choose a random element from Java.util.Deque

Tags: java, random, performance, deque

Usually I use the Deque for it's intended purpose but infrequently I need to choose a random element from it.  I use the below code to do so, but it requires iterating through the Deque. Is there a more efficient way to do it?

```
Iterator<T> iterator = mDeque.iterator();
int target = mRand.nextInt(mDeque.size());
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    if (target == 0) {
        chosenElement = iterator.next();
        break;
    } else {
        iterator.next();
        target--;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Your current approach is O(n), I don't think there is a more efficient way to do it than this. _"Unlike the List interface, this interface does not provide support for indexed access to elements."_

Comment: I suppose you could create your own Deque implementation that wraps an ArrayList for its backing storage, and add a get method that delegates to the get method of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an [ArrayDeque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html), use `toArray` and then use the index directly (`[target]` for your example)

Comment: as far as time efficiency goes, you'd have to check. not sure how long `toArray` takes to execute, it'll probably depend on the size of your deque.

Comment: It does make a defensive copy of the array, so it's O(n).

Comment: While not any more efficient, this answer leads to much easier to read code.

Comment: that is what I thought you might be going for. glad it helped.